# scope of objects stored in the registry-class php

Tags: php, registry, scope

I have a Registry where I store my request, validator, database and router objects. So for validation of my forms, I use a method in class MyForm, where the input fields are checked. When user input is incorrect, then Registry::getInstance()->validator->setErrors($errors) is called, so that errors are stored in the Registry and get available anywhere in code.

That's why i call Registry::getInstance()->validator->getErrors() in MyView.php

```
</head><body>
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="newuser.php" method="post">
<?php
    $errors = Registry::getInstance()->validator->getErrors();
    if($errors) {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<p>'. $error . '</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Though $MyForm->isValid() fills in the errors here in Registry::getInstance()->validator->setErrors($errors) correctly, clearly to see with var_dump(Registry::getInstance()), the validator object is null, when called in MyView.php.

So it still is the same object. But errortexts are gone. Why?

And where is the best place to store errortexts when validation in MyForm.php is false, so that i can grab the text in MyView.php?

Edit:
this is the registry

```
class Registry {
private static $_instance = null;
private $_cache = array();

public static function getInstance()
{
    if(null === self::$_instance) {
        self::$_instance = new self;
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}


public function __set($index, $value) {

    if(!empty($index) && is_string($index)  && !array_key_exists($index, $this->_cache)) {
        $this->_cache[$index] = $value;
    }
    else {
        // Errorhandling here ...
    }
}

public function __get($name)
{
    if(array_key_exists($name, $this->_cache) && !empty($this->_cache[$name])) {
        return $this->_cache[$name];
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public function __unset($index)
{
    unset($this->_cache[$index]);
}


private function __construct() {}
private function __clone() { }
```

}

I guess, it has to do with the communication between the View and the Controller. Somehow it does not work. I don't know where to include the View, which is just html, not generated. This is my RegistrationController

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller {
public function execute()
{
    $form = new RegistrationForm;
    if($this->request->issetPost()) {
        $posts = $this->request->getPosts();
        if($form->isValid($posts)) {
            // [..save .]
        }
    }
}
```

}
I am still confused with the view. Like:

```
switch($page) {
case 'index':
    // ..
    break;
case 'news':
    // ..
    break;
case 'register_new_user':
    $newuser = new RegistrationController;
    $newuser->sign();
    break;
```

} Where is the place to call a view, tell it that action was done with errors, so there is text in the Registry-Container for the view to show?

Comment: You will need to show the code of your registry.

Answer (score 1):

While your variables will survive in a single request, subsequent requests will still have a pristine `Registry` object without the variables set. The solution would be to store (a part of) the `Registry` singleton in a session, and on the first instantiation load those variables. Something like:

```
....
if(null === self::$_instance) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    self::$_instance = isset($_SESSION['Registry']) ? $_SESSION['Registry'] : new self();
    $_SESSION['Registry'] = self::$_instance;
}
....
```

Or just a portion:

```
....
if(null === self::$_instance) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    self::$_instance = new self();
    if(isset($_SESSION['RegistryPersistent'])) self::$_instance->_cache['persistent'] = &$_SESSION['RegistryPersistent'];
}
....
```